# Reactjs node gyp error when installing node sass

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass, npm-install

I was trying to build a new project on React and I want to use SASS, but when I start installing `npm install node-sass` it gives me this **node-gyp error**

```
jake@Ehys-Air portfolio % npm install node-sass
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.4.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.9.10"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.4.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.4.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.4.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.4.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.4.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools") does not exist
npm ERR! Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
npm ERR! See `man xcode-select` for more details.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jake/Development/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jake/.npm/_logs/2022-07-23T07_23_01_464Z-debug-0.log
```

I am not sure why this is happening because before I used to use SASS/SCSS on my previous react builds. This is kind of frustrating to be honest for a newbie dev like me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem by installing `xcode-select --install` because I don't have this command line tools `npm ERR! xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools") does not exist`